# Non-copyable elements in a std::vector of std::lists

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have a non-copyable class, simplified as follows:

```
struct NonCopyable
{
    NonCopyable() = default;
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable&&) = default;
    NonCopyable& operator = (NonCopyable&&) = default;
};
```

I store the objects of this class in various std::lists. At one point I have an *empty* std::vector of these lists, which I would like to resize to contain a fixed number of *empty* lists. However, this complains about the lack of a NonCopyable copy constructor, even though (as far as I can see) it shouldn't be trying to construct any NonCopyables!

```
std::vector<std::list<NonCopyable>> v; // OK
v.resize(4);                           // ERROR
v.emplace_back();                      // ERROR
std::list<NonCopyable> l;              // OK
v.push_back(l);                        // ERROR (unsurprisingly)
v.push_back(std::move(l));             // ERROR
```

Why is this? Is there any way to do this without making the class copyable?

I'm using VS2017 with /std:c++17 in case that makes any difference.

---

Here's the full error output from just trying to resize (first two lines above).

```
1>------ Build started: Project: testcore, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>testcard.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xmemory0(881): error C2280: 'NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>[...]\testcard.cpp(30): note: see declaration of 'NonCopyable::NonCopyable'
1>[...]\testcard.cpp(30): note: 'NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &)': function was explicitly deleted
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(711): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const NonCopyable&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_node<NonCopyable,std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<NonCopyable>>::void_pointer>>,
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Objty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(716): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::construct<_Ty,const NonCopyable&>(_Alloc &,_Objty *const ,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<std::_List_node<NonCopyable,std::_Default_allocator_traits<std::allocator<NonCopyable>>::void_pointer>>,
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Objty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(947): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *std::_List_buy<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Buynode<const NonCopyable&>(std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *,std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<NonCopyable>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(950): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *std::_List_buy<_Ty,_Alloc>::_Buynode<const NonCopyable&>(std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *,std::_List_node<_Ty,std::_Default_allocator_traits<_Alloc>::void_pointer> *,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<NonCopyable>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(1308): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert<const NonCopyable&>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(1308): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert<const NonCopyable&>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,const NonCopyable &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(1265): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert_range<_Iter>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,_Iter,_Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<NonCopyable>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(1264): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Insert_range<_Iter>(std::_List_unchecked_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>,std::_Iterator_base0>,_Iter,_Iter,std::forward_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<NonCopyable>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(800): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert<std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,void>(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<NonCopyable>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(800): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>::insert<std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,void>(std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>,_Iter,_Iter)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable,
1>            _Iter=std::_List_const_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<NonCopyable>>>
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\list(796): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list(const std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\xmemory0(881): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>::list(const std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\vector(1812): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\vector(1811): note: while compiling class template member function 'std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>> *std::vector<std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::_Udefault(std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> *,const unsigned __int64)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.15.26726\include\vector(1479): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>> *std::vector<std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>::_Udefault(std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>> *,const unsigned __int64)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>[...]\testcard.cpp(37): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<std::list<NonCopyable,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::list<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=NonCopyable
1>        ]
1>Done building project "testcore.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` is [not noexcept-movable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list), but is copyable. Therefore, `std::vector` prefers `list`'s the copy-constructor over its move-constructor, regardless.

To work around the issue, you have to wrap your `std::list` in a class that is not copyable.

Comment: Thanks. What if the NonCopyable class was also not movable? (Moving objects between lists would still be possible I believe, since it doesn't invalidate references,)

Comment: @UriZarfaty It would be possible to move the list's nodes around using `splice`, but `std::vector` does not know about it.

Comment: So it's about QoI. No wonder Clang and GCC accept it. https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/list#L1315

Comment: @StoryTeller It is not exactly QoI, but a matter of following the Standard literally. I do not see a `noexcept` specification on the move constructor [in the list synopsis](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/list.overview). That said, I agree that the Clang's and GCC's behavior is preferable.

Comment: @j6t - The standard has a debatable QoI too. Well, quality of specification would be more exact, but the point still holds.

Comment: MSVC's `list` uses a dynamically-allocated sentinel node, so the move constructor can't be `noexcept`. (The tradeoff is that things like `swap` doesn't invalidate end iterators.)

Comment: Is a `std::list<T>` really supposed to be copyable when `T` isn't `Cpp17CopyInsertable`? I haven't read the standards before and have a little trouble understanding the [container.requirements](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:containers.container.requirements).

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is impossible that `list<T>` is copyable when the `T` is not copyable. The point here is that `vector<T>` is very paranoid and does not use move-construction of `T` if such move-construction can throw exceptions.

Comment: Ok, but if `std::list<T>` really isn't copyable when `T` isn't, I don't really understand how my hack (the `xxx::list` below) could make it work? The only thing I did was to `delete` the copying if `T` isn't copyable and then the `vector` used move-construction.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The reason why it compiles is that when `T` is not copyable, but still move-constructible (like your `xxx::list`), then `vector<T>` must use `T`'s move constructor, even at the risk that it throws an exception, because there is no safer choice.

Comment: @j6t yes, but why is `std::is_copy_constructible<std::list<NonCopyable>>::value` true (even in gcc/clang)?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Because nowhere in the specification of `std::list<T>` it is said that "the copy-constructor is excluded from the overload set if `T` is not copy-constructible". Therefore, `std::list`'s copy constructor is always available, and that is all that `std::is_copy_constructible` looks at.

Comment: Ok, that's where my problems understanding of how to read the standard shows. `X(a)` and `X u(a);` both `Requires: T is Cpp17CopyInsertable into X`. I interpreted that as those therefor shouldn't be available in this case.

Comment: These `Requires` clauses are directives for the programmer, not the compiler. If the conditions are violated, you get what you deserve; at best it does not compile, at worst it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As @j6t pointed out, it seems it can't be done. A vector with a `std::list` with non-copyable elements can not be expanded according to the standard (...). If it was my private project I'd actually consider something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>

namespace xxx {
    // <flame_bait>
    template<class T, class Enable = void>
    struct list : std::list<T> {
        list() : std::list<T>() {}
        list(list&&) = default;
        list& operator=(list&&) = default;
        list(const list&) = delete;
        list& operator=(const list&) = delete;
    };

    template<class T>
    struct list<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value>::type> : std::list<T> {};
    // </flame_bait>
}

struct NonCopyable
{
    int m_id;
    NonCopyable(int id = 0) : m_id(id) {}
    NonCopyable(const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable& operator = (const NonCopyable&) = delete;
    NonCopyable(NonCopyable&&) noexcept = default;
    NonCopyable& operator = (NonCopyable&&) noexcept = default;
    ~NonCopyable() = default;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const NonCopyable&);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const NonCopyable& nc) {
    os << "I am not a free man, I am number " << nc.m_id;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<xxx::list<NonCopyable>> v;
    v.resize(4);                    // now working 

    int id = 0;
    for (auto& l : v) {
        l.emplace_back(++id);       // emplace_back one NonCopyable per list  
    }

    xxx::list<NonCopyable> li;      // Create a separate list
    li.emplace_back(++id);          // create one...
    v.emplace_back(std::move(li));  // and move list to vector is now working

    for (auto& l : v) {
        for (auto& nc : l) {
            std::cout << nc << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
I am not a free man, I am number 1
I am not a free man, I am number 2
I am not a free man, I am number 3
I am not a free man, I am number 4
I am not a free man, I am number 5
```

Comment: Seems I missed the part where `v.resize(4);` fails. What's the error message from that line?

Comment: `error C2280: 'NonCopyable::NonCopyable(const NonCopyable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. I've added the full error output for that to the post.

Comment: Great! How odd though ... :-) I'll give it a try in VS when I get home.

Comment: Just to make it worse: `v.reserve(4);` gives the same error.

Comment: I added a `xxx::list` replacement for `std::list` that hopefully should work as a container for both copyable and non-copyable objects. I''m terrible with templates though so be aware ...